# ViewSVN fails to run saying unsupported URL

Tags: php, svn

I'm trying to setup [ViewSVN](http://viewsvn.berlios.de/) for viewing our subversion repository.
My SVN repository uses https for access. However, irrespective of supplying svn://, svn+ssh:// or https:// in the viewsvn configuration for my svn repository, I always get this in my apache log:

```
svn: URL protocol is not supported 'https://my.repository.com'
```

Everything of course works perfectly when running from the commandline. 
my localconfig.php file defines the svn root server as

```
$config['svnroot']='https://my.repository.com';
```

One other thing- I am using [JavaSVN](http://svnkit.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to have multiple versions of SVN installed, e.g. ViewSVN using /usr/bin/svn whereas you are using /usr/local/bin/svn or something like that?

---

[**EDIT**]
I don't know JavaSVN but maybe it behaves differently when run by different users. Maybe it doesn't load additional plugins you need to handle different protocols. Do you have superuser access to your machine? Try to run the checkout from the command line as the web server user:

```
su nobody
svn checkout https://...
```

Comment: no- you have to specify the path to the binary in the configuration and I've set it to the same one I'm using. It is the only svn client on the system.

Answer (score 0):

I have the "port number" and the "root folder" added in svnroot, like the follwoing

$config['svnroot']='https://my.repository.com:***8088/svn***';

I use TortoiseSVN and it shows my svnroot, I think JAVASVN has the same feature.